# remove facet.by label from sublot title in violinboxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

As the title says I need to remove the label related to the *facet.by* from the title of each subplot in a violin box plot, using ggplot2.

Read the data and create the plot

```
 plotIt <- read.table("tryit.csv", sep="\t", header=T)

 p <- ggviolin(data, x = "label", y = "aMeasure",  fill="label", palette=rainbowcols, + facet.by="timepoint", add.params = list(fill = "white"), short.panel.labs = FALSE, main=paste("measuring", tolower(reg), sep=" "), ylab="a measure", xlab="", ylim=c(0,8)) + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), axis.text.x=element_blank())

 advanced <- p + stat_compare_means(comparisons = list(c("tone", "ttwo")), method = "t.test", paired=F, label.y=7.5) + geom_boxplot(width=0.05)
```

The question is: how to remove the "timepoint" label from the title of each subplot?

EDIT:

these are the packages I'm using for plotting are ggplot and ggpubr

[image: the plot]

Comment: Possibly `theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
strip.text = element_blank()
)`

Comment: would you like to just remove `timepoint: `?

Comment: @matt: that removes everything, not only `timepoint:`

Comment: @dbo, yes: that is exactly what I need. I must keep the day* but no `timepoint`

Comment: @tom, that doesn't do the trick but I'll look into the link you provided

Comment: With `library(tidyverse)` for `mutate()` I'd try something along the lines of `plotIt %>% mutate(timepoint = gsub("timepoint: ", "", timepoint)`

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, and what packages you're using (`ggpubr`?)

Comment: @camille, you're right. I was going to upload a sample file. Also I edited the question with the packages I'm importing

Comment: @dbo, what do you mean with "along the lines". I mean...your suggestion is supposed to substitute `timepoint: ` with nothing but when I plot, I need to specify which column of the dataset will be considered. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the desired result by using:

```
short.panel.labs = TRUE
```

This is also the default behaviour of `facet`, so you can completely remove `short.panel.labs`.
And it doesn't matter whether you use `TRUE`/`FALSE` or `T`/`F`, but if I remember correctly, the full notation is recommended for clarity.

Comment: that is perfect! I totally missed this part in the help. Now that you mentioned it I found it. Many thanks!